# Sort files in a directory by timstamp string in file name after second -

Tags: java, file, sorting, arraylist, directory

I'm trying to sort the files in a directory by unix time-stamp. Following is the files name in a directory.

```
20151102-2148040042-1446522484838-Game21500052-x.realtime
20121102-2148010042-1446522484138-Game21500052-x.realtime
```

I need to get the files after sorting unix timestamp after second - . How I can do that in java?

I am able to do that in python like below

```
def extract_timestamp(filename):
    timestamp = filename.split('-')[2]
     return timestamp
directory = '/home/ubuntu/assdd/'
# Get all files from the path
log_files = os.listdir(directory)

# Sort files by timestamp
log_files.sort(key=extract_timestamp)

# Get full path of each file
files = [os.path.join(directory,data_file) for data_file in log_files]
```

Answer (score 2):

A very direct approach:

```
List<String> fileNames = ... ;

List<String> sortedFileNames = fileNames.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(s -> Long.parseLong(s.split("-")[2])))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `sorted` call deserves some explanation:

It creates a `Comparator` that compares `Long` values (`Comparator<Long>`).  It gets the `Long` value by splitting the fileName String into parts separated by `-`.  It then takes the third element of the resulting split, which contains a number.  It then converts this number to a long.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort all files with a custom comparator, here you can parse the timestamp and compare file's timestamp. The simplest way is:

```
    private String getTimestamp(File file) {
    return file.getName().substring(20, 33);
}

public List<File> sortFilesInDir(String yourpath) {
    File folder = new File(yourpath);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    if (listOfFiles == null) {
        return null;
    }
    List<File> files = Arrays.asList(listOfFiles);

    Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            return getTimestamp(o1).compareTo(getTimestamp(o2));
        }
    });
    return files;
}
```

If you have a lot of files and you don't want to parse timestamp every time, you can save each file to a record like:

```
    private static class FileRecord {
    private File file;
    private String timestamp;

    public FileRecord(File file) {
        this.file = file;
        this.timestamp = file.getName().substring(20, 33);
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}

private List<FileRecord> convertFilesToRecords(File[] files) {
    List<FileRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : files) {
        records.add(new FileRecord(file));
    }
    return records;
}

public List<File> sortFilesInDir(String yourpath) {
    File folder = new File(yourpath);
    List<FileRecord> records = convertFilesToRecords(folder.listFiles());

    Collections.sort(records, new Comparator<FileRecord>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(FileRecord o1, FileRecord o2) {
            return o1.getTimestamp().compareTo(o2.getTimestamp());
        }
    });
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    for (FileRecord record : records) {
        files.add(record.getFile());
    }
    return files;
}
```